# Can I replace a laptop battery with one that has the same voltage but different model/serial numbers?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an Acer Aspire E15 E5-576G that uses battery model AS16A5K (14.8V 2800mAh/41.4Wh), and I want to replace it with battery number AL15A32 from an Acer Aspire E5-473 (14.8V 2500mAh/37Wh).

- The charging current for mine is 1.536A @ 17.2V max, while the AL15A32's is 1.26A @ 17.4V, and, as far as I know, the batteries need to be of the same voltage

Is it safe for me to replace the battery with the one from E5-473?

Comment: I would recommend to either contact Acer or a major laptop battery supplier that sells directly to consumers, as a laptop battery's part number will list what other batteries are compatible to replace it with. It's generally not the actual batteries themselves that would pose the issue _(laptop batteries are almost always banks of 18650's and many laptop models offer extended capacity batteries)_, but the battery's PCB that interacts with the power brick.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the battery physically fits in your machine.
The voltage is the same, so that is fine.

The power output is lower, so it will not last as long without AC, but the charging circuit should charge it properly.

Some batteries have chips to match the battery with the computer, so watch for that.

So long as it fits properly, you should be fine.